# Mongoose Query All Group Docs if One Group Doc Has a Certain Value

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Lets assume I save this simple model:

```
name: String
group: String
last: Boolean
```

And have this example Data:

```
Peter, A, false
Klaus, A, true

James, B, false
Bond, B, false
```

I only want to get results from groups which have one last entry with the value true. In this case, I want to have
`Klaus and Peter` but I don't want to have `James and Bond`.

Comment: PS: I can do two queries: where I query `{last:true}` and distinct the group value to make a second query. But I would like to have it in one query.

Comment: It's not wise to attempt this. The means for document retention in MongoDB aggregation is pushing content into an array, which is certain to break BSON limits in most real world situations. Besides, you really don't want to group anything. Just retrieve items of one particular "type" where one of their number happens to contain a particular flag value. You are therefore doing it in the most efficient way already.